# How to setup a different html output directory for coverage report with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py

Using coverage with pytests is a very useful tool.

Html reporting allows for nice output, however through command line, can't find an option to modify the default output directory (htmlcov)

example command line:

```
python -m pytest lib_being_tested\tests --cov lib_being_tested.module --cov-report=html
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This configuration option isn't part of `pytest-cov`.

In the configuration file for the underlying tool `coverage.py`, which is called `.coveragerc` by default, you can add:

```
[html]
directory = differentname
```

See the documentation for details: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/doc/config.rst

Comment: The docs are also available at their canonical location: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html

Answer (score 33):

now (3 years later) you can change the default output directory directly in command line:

```
python -m pytest --cov --cov-report=html:reports/html_dir --cov-report=xml:reports/coverage.xml lib_being_tested.module
```

Missing directories are created on the fly

[Simeon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27537412/3216318) is still relevant to choose this output directory through coverage configuration file